# Rendering an iFrame within a React Portal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, react-hooks, react-portal

I was creating a `Logger` service which would track events within my application. To make the `Logger` service generic, I used React's Portal to capture the events fired in my application. The basic idea of my application is:

```js
<LoggerPortal>
   <App>
</LoggerPortal>
```

This worked well for my use case until the point that I used an `iFrame` within my application.

Consider a very simple component that renders an iFrame:

```js
const Frame = props => {
  const refiFrame = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(refiFrame.current.contentDocument);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <iframe id="i-framed-you" title="original-iframe-title" ref={refiFrame} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Now, when I render this `Frame` component above without the Portal wrapped around it, the `iframe.contentDocument` logs as expected.

```js
ReactDOM.render(<Frame />,rootElement)
```

But when I render the `Frame` component wrapped within a Portal the value of `iFrame.contentDocument` is **null**.

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <LoggerPortal>
    <Frame />
  </LoggerPortal>,
  rootElement
);
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/portal-iframe-3s6w4) that has an app that depicts my problem. Has anyone seen this issue when using portals and iFrame? Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2):

Tricky problem!

`useRef` doesn't cause a re-render when you make changes to have React add or remove DOM nodes.  In your case, attaching an `iframe` to your `<Portal>`'s `props.children`, thus your console is returning `null`.  You'll have to use a callback ref instead: `useCallback`

So, to get the ref to your iframe, you can try:

```
  let refiFrame =  useCallback(node => {
    refiFrame = node
  });
```

Here is a working modified version of your codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/portal-iframe-dmmnx